# TypeScript jsdoc for interface properties

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

I have a TypeScript interface with a single-character property name (a design constraint).  I would like to use JSDoc to document this interface to help with auto-complete in vscode.

Here's the current interface:

```
export interface ISource {
    b: string
    d: string
    f: string
    h: string
    M: number
    L: number
    P: number
    n: string
    r: string
    u: string
    p: string
}
```

Non-working attempts are:

```
/**
* @typedef {object} ISource
* @property {string} ISource.b - Bias: bias_text[rating.bias[0]],
* @property {string} ISource.d - Domain: rating.domain.replace(/^www\./, ""),
* @property {string} ISource.f - FacebookUrl: _.lowerCase(rating.facebook_url),
* @property {string} ISource.h - Host: `https://${rating.domain}`,
* @property {number} ISource.M - MozRankUrl: rating.moz_rank_url,
* @property {number} ISource.L - MozLinks: rating.moz_links,
* @property {number} ISource.P - MozPopularity: rating.moz_popularity,
* @property {string} ISource.n - Source: rating.source,
* @property {string} ISource.r - Reporting: _.upperCase(_.kebabCase(_.first(rating.factual_reporting))),
* @property {string} ISource.u - Url: url,
* @property {string} ISource.p - Path: path,
*/

export interface ISource {
    b: string
    d: string
    f: string
    h: string
    M: number
    L: number
    P: number
    n: string
    r: string
    u: string
    p: string
}
```

and

```
export interface ISource {
    b: string /** @property {string} b - Bias: bias_text[rating.bias[0]], */;
    d: string /** @property {string} d - Domain: rating.domain.replace(/^www\./, ""), */;
    f: string /** @property {string} f - FacebookUrl: _.lowerCase(rating.facebook_url), */;
    h: string /** @property {string} h - Host: `https://${rating.domain}`, */;
    M: number /** @property {string} M - MozRankUrl: rating.moz_rank_url, */;
    L: number /** @property {string} L - MozLinks: rating.moz_links, */;
    P: number /** @property {string} P - MozPopularity: rating.moz_popularity, */;
    n: string /** @property {string} n - Source: rating.source, */;
    r: string /** @property {string} r - Reporting: _.upperCase(_.kebabCase(_.first(rating.factual_reporting))), */;
    u: string /** @property {string} u - Url: url, */;
    p: string /** @property {string} p - Path: path, */;
}
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Just put the doc comment before each property:

```
export interface ISource {
    /**
     * Bias: bias_text[rating.bias[0]],
     */
    b: string

    /**
     * Domain: `rating.domain.replace(/^www\./, "")`
     */
    d: string
    ...
}
```

(Also, don't use type annotations in JSDocs inside TS files; the compiler and tooling will ignore these types)

Comment: is there an alternative to this, like function @param. this makes the properties definition very long.

Comment: You can format the comment to be a single line: `/** Docs here */ b: string`

Comment: Is there a way to share a comment across multiple types?  I have 3 type definitions that all have the same property. This is used for overriding.  I don't want to have to copy paste the same documentation on all three type definitions

Comment: Sounds like you should be using inheritance @user1015434

Comment: Inheritance won’t work in this scenario.  I have 7 different type variations were based on propA, you can only pick specific values for propB.  But the documentation around propA is the same for all 7 type variations

Comment: @user1015434 You could just use `@see` and `@link`. Also, regarding the suggestion that was made, inheritance sucks, composition is better. Inheritance always creates that complicated prototype chain, in addition to not being the best suited concept to begin with in many cases, unless all you know and breath day to day is OOP and are not used to anything else. There's `@borrows` too, maybe, whose description sounds like it's made for this (https://jsdoc.app/tags-borrows.html)